# Setting up stack for MS-DOS Int 24h Critical Error Handler

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I'm trying to build an MS-DOS emulator and trying to add support for custom critical error handler. The application overwrites the in-built DOS critical error handler with something like this:

```
mov dx, seg int24handler
mov ds, dx
mov dx, offset int24handler
mov ax, 2524h
int 21h
```

Then when various file operations fail I trigger

```
int 24h
```

This is fine at passing control to the custom critical error handler, but in some scenarios instead of coming back from the int 24 handler the CS register is corrupt and tries to execute memory where there isn't any code. But the code runs fine in real MS-DOS. I'm currently working on adding a debugging feature to help collect more detail. However in the meantime I want to try and verify my stack is set up like this diagram from Advanced MS-DOS Programming prior to passing control to INT24:

[image]

I am trying to work out what equivalent CPU instructions would help set up stack like that diagram. From what I can tell from publicly releases MS-DOS 2.0 source code at https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/04a3d20ff411409ab98474892b2bb1713bde0f7f/v2.0/source/CTRLC.ASM I need to backup and restore SS & SP register. INT 24 is executed with code **INT     int_fatal_abort**
However I don't see how this helps set up the stack as per the diagram? Is there anything I'm missing?

```
        XCHG    AX,DI                   ; Error code in DI, count in AX
        AND     DI,STECODE              ; And off status bits
        CMP     DI,WRECODE              ; Write Protect Error?
        JNZ     NOSETWRPERR
        PUSH    AX
        MOV     AL,ES:[BP.dpb_drive]
        MOV     BYTE PTR [WPERR],AL              ; Flag drive with WP error
        POP     AX
NOSETWRPERR:
        SUB     AX,CX                   ; Number of sectors successfully transferred
        ADD     DX,AX                   ; First sector number to retry
        PUSH    DX
        MUL     ES:[BP.dpb_sector_size]          ; Number of bytes transferred
        POP     DX
        ADD     BX,AX                   ; First address for retry
        XOR     AH,AH                   ; Flag disk section in error
        CMP     DX,ES:[BP.dpb_first_FAT]    ; In reserved area?
        JB      ERRINT
        INC     AH                      ; Flag for FAT
        CMP     DX,ES:[BP.dpb_dir_sector]   ; In FAT?
        JB      ERRINT
        INC     AH
        CMP     DX,ES:[BP.dpb_first_sector]       ; In directory?
        JB      ERRINT
        INC     AH                      ; Must be in data area
ERRINT:
        SHL     AH,1                    ; Make room for read/write bit
        OR      AH,BYTE PTR [READOP]
        entry   FATAL
        MOV     AL,ES:[BP.dpb_drive]      ; Get drive number
        entry   FATAL1
        MOV     WORD PTR [EXITHOLD+2],ES
        MOV     WORD PTR [EXITHOLD],BP  ; The only things we preserve
        LES     SI,ES:[BP.dpb_driver_addr]
        MOV     BP,ES                   ; BP:SI points to the device involved
FATALC:
        CMP     BYTE PTR [ERRORMODE],0
        JNZ     SETIGN                  ; No INT 24s if already INT 24
        MOV     [CONTSTK],SP
        PUSH    SS
        POP     ES
ASSUME  ES:DOSGROUP
        CLI                             ; Prepare to play with stack
        INC     BYTE PTR [ERRORMODE]    ; Flag INT 24 in progress
        DEC     BYTE PTR [INDOS]        ; INT 24 handler might not return
        MOV     SS,[user_SS]
ASSUME  SS:NOTHING
        MOV     SP,ES:[user_SP]         ; User stack pointer restored
        INT     int_fatal_abort         ; Fatal error interrupt vector, must preserve ES
        MOV     ES:[user_SP],SP         ; restore our stack
        MOV     ES:[user_SS],SS
        MOV     SP,ES
        MOV     SS,SP
ASSUME  SS:DOSGROUP
        MOV     SP,[CONTSTK]
        INC     BYTE PTR [INDOS]        ; Back in the DOS
        MOV     BYTE PTR [ERRORMODE],0  ; Back from INT 24
        STI
IGNRET:
        LES     BP,[EXITHOLD]
ASSUME  ES:NOTHING
        CMP     AL,2
        JZ      error_abort
        MOV     BYTE PTR [WPERR],-1              ;Forget about WP error
        return

SETIGN:
        XOR     AL,AL                   ;Flag ignore
        JMP     SHORT IGNRET

error_abort:
        PUSH    SS
        POP     DS
ASSUME  DS:DOSGROUP
        CMP     BYTE PTR [CONSWAP],0
        JZ      NOSWAP2
        invoke  SWAPBACK
NOSWAP2:
        MOV     BYTE PTR [exit_Type],Exit_hard_error
        MOV     DS,[CurrentPDB]
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING
```

Comment: I don't see any code that sets up the stack layout in the image. Also `MOV SP,ES; MOV SS,SP` seems very strange. Also also it's not obvious what ctrl+c has to do with int24.

Comment: I think because that assembly file also has the code for the Ctrl+C handler and they dumped int 24 handler in same code file

Comment: "I need to backup and restore SS & SP register" The code you've shown only preserves DOS's `sp` (in word `CONTSTK`) and resets `ss` to the DOS DATA segment (in `es`) after the `int 24h` returns. The remaining setup is just to restore the user stack frame as created by the interrupt 21h entrypoint. If you don't use a separate DOS stack for your handler then you don't have to modify `ss:sp` at all, just push registers in the order indicated by the book.